# cURL - Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl (post PHP update)

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https

I know there are dozens of questions about this particular topic, but the usual suggestions don't really seem to help. I have checked the server under the root account and the specific account I'm working with and in both cases (if they even can be different) SSL is listed as a feature and HTTPS is listed as a protocol.

My cURL functions were working fine until yesterday when we upgraded PHP from ~5.1/5.2 to 5.4.26. My assumption was that PHP and/or cURL were compiled without SSL support, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If it helps, the functions are calling Appcelerator's cloud services. This is one of the login functions, the first to throw the "trying to get property of non-object" error because `$res` is false:

```
function login() {
    $url = 'https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=<MY_APP_KEY>';
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'login' => '<MY_APP_LOGIN>',
            'password' => '<MY_APP_PASSWORD>'
        )
    );
    $curl_session = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl_session, $options);
    $res = curl_exec($curl_session);
    curl_close($curl_session);
    $this->session_id = json_decode($res)->meta->session_id;
}
```

Is it possible that even though SSL and HTTPS are listed that they're not actually in effect? Is there a way to check and if necessary fix that?

Comment: Try set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` / `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` options to `false`

Comment: You say "SSL is listed as a feature and HTTPS is listed as a protocol.", but how did you do that exactly? To me it sounds like you checked for something different than what causes your code to fail.

Comment: @DanielStenberg SSH to server root: -bash-3.2# curl-config --feature
SSL
IPv6
libz
IDN
NTLM
-bash-3.2# curl-config --protocols
HTTP
HTTPS
FTP
FTPS
FILE
TELNET
LDAP
DICT
TFTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem is that you have more than one libcurl version installed in your machine, so your checking as root returns the info about a global installation while your PHP environment runs a different version.

In your PHP program you can instead run [curl_version()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php) and see what it says regarding SSL support and versions etc.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Even though I checked the curl config on this particular account, running curl_version() shows ssl_version as NULL, ssl_version_number as 0, and naturally https is missing from the protocols array. So how would I go about enabling SSL? Do I have to completely reconfigure Apache?

Comment: No, it is the libcurl version your PHP uses that needs to get built with SSL support. You should probably try to make sure you use the single and only libcurl install and have that use SSL...

Comment: Yep, looks like we'll have to rebuild Apache. Thanks.